# What is the Windows equivalent of `{} +` in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple batch file to compile some code and I can't for the life of me figure out or find any information on how to do this.

On Linux, I'm doing this:

```
find ./bin-int/ -type f -name '*.o' -exec rgblink -o ./bin/lapis.gb -n ./bin-int/symbols.sym {} +
```

This basically finds all the files in ./bin-int/ with the extension .o, and use them as the input variable for the command rgblink.

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this on Windows. The closest I got is

```
for /r ".\bin-int" %%i in (*.o); do rgblink -o ./bin/lapis.gb  -n ./bin-int/symbols.sym %%i
```

which is wrong because I don't want to run the command once for EACH file. I want the EVERY file to be the input for the command, at the same time.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: batch files do not use arrays, so what you'd need to do is to create a variable containing the first filename, and continue to append each new file to it, using the for loop method, until they have all been iterated. Once you've done that run a single rgblink command passing that multistring variable as the final argument.

Comment: there's no such thing as "Linux shell" because there are many shells that run on Linux like bash, sh, zsh, csh, ksh, pwsh...

Comment: @phuclv I'm using whatever comes with Linux Mint, and most shells have similar commands. But anyways, that clearly wasn't the point of this question.

Comment: I've rolled back your question content @TypeDefinition. Please do not post solutions in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to append the list to a variable first, then run the list in the command:

```
@for /r ".\bin-int" %%i in (*.o) do @call set "list=%%list%% %%i"
rgblink -o ./bin-int/lapis.gb  -n ./bin-int/symbols.sym%list%
```

this is untested as I cannot confirm what your list should look like exactly, but you'll get the idea.